# Download file link not working in Angular

Tags: angular, download, href

I have a 33 KB pdf file in my Angular website application at

`src/app/components/landing-page/res/File.pdf`

In my landing-page.component.html, which is located inside the landing-page folder, I wrote the following line to allow the file to be downloaded.

```
My File <a href="./res/File.pdf" download="File.pdf">here</a>.
```

However, when I open the app in browser using ng serve, and click on the link, a 705 B `File.pdf` is downloaded which can't be opened. The hyperlink is shown to be linked to `http://localhost:4200/res/File.pdf` and I think this is the source of the problem because this file path may only be valid in the angular framework.

Comment: you should add the full path to it.

Comment: move your file to assests folder. Then refer it from that directory as /assets/filename.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this, cases like the following, the browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.

- Links that contain target element:

  `<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
- Absolute links:

  `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
- Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base
  is defined:

  `<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

As per your issue, you should use the following way.
If you project path like shown below

[image]

Then below is the proper way of handling download file.

```
<a target="_self" href="../../assets/File.pdf" download="File.pdf">here</a>
```

make sure your **href** path is correct. Moreover assets folder should be outside angular app folder otherwise it won't work.

[Angular Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html-link-rewriting)

I hope this will help you. If you have any problems or suggestions let me know.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. However, I didn't have to put ../../assets/File.pdf. Just doing assets/File.pdf worked

Comment: yes but it differs based on the folder structure you have. anyway cool :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```html
<a  href="../../assets/file.txt" download="file.txt">here</a>
```

the file *file.txt* must be inside the assets folder.